# Maven Antlr3 plugin generates code in weird location

Tags: maven, antlr, antlr3

I am using plugin and Antlr version 3.3 for a project under H:/compiler

I have a tokens file under my src/main/antlr3/com/cbc/example directory called CBCTokens.g. In the same package i have a parser grammar file called MyScribe.g that references the tokens using tokenVocab=CBCTokens. I also have a tree grammar in the same directory.

However when i try to execute the build, i get an error on the very first file the plugin encounters saying:

```
Error(1): cannot write file : java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\compiler\target\generated-sources\antlr3\H:\compiler\src\main\antlr3\CBCTokensLexer.java (The filname, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

It seems to me that the plugin is determining the output path using some weird combination of baseDir and the default output directory.

What configuration am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: [pom.xml](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6CBDE11DA0BC715C!262&authkey=!AJrBy_6vFdORqIY&ithint=file%2c.xml)

Comment: Is this pom part of a multi-module-build ?

Comment: Yes it is, but the top level pom.xml only defines a couple of properties and a list of modules in addition to a standard section for maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 0):

First best thing is never to generate code into `src/main/` folder whatever. This means for your configuration just remove `<outputDirectory>` tag and remove the `<sourceDirectory>` cause it's the default of the antlr3-maven-plugin.

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <printGrammar>false</printGrammar>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>antlr</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to help.I found this [Nabble thread](http://antlr.1301665.n2.nabble.com/antlr3-maven-plugin-tries-to-generate-the-xxxLexer-java-when-using-a-combined-lexer-parser-grammar-td7143628.html) which seems related. And if it indeed is, there doesn't seem to have been any progress in resolving such an issue.